# Stability of Ricci-flat Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ by small deformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, kahler-manifolds

As we know, a compact Kähler manifold remains Kähler after any infinitesimal deformations. Since a compact complex manifold in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ is bimeromorphic to a Kähler manifold, it was conjectured that Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ is also in class $\mathcal C$ of Fujiki after a small deformation, but later, [Campana91](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01459236.pdf) and [LP92](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1992-05-02/S0894-0347-1992-1137099-7/S0894-0347-1992-1137099-7.pdf) proved that it was wrong, the class $\mathcal C$ of Fujiki is not stable by small deformations. The counterexample even exists in dimension 3, and in dimension $\geq 4$ even a Moishezon manifold has a small deformation which is not in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$.

Here, my question is, if a compact complex manifold in class $\mathcal C$ of Fujiki with canonical bundle trivial, then after a small deformation, is it still in class $\mathcal C$ of Fujiki? Or any other conditions which make the small deformations of Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ still in class $\mathcal C$? for example, admits a symplectic structure?